# What happened to Barasui ( Ichigo Mashimaro's author )?

Tags: strawberry-marshmallow, barasui

[*Ichigo Mashimaro*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/371/Ichigo_Mashimaro) was first published in 2002. There is no information about the author except on Wikipedia. His last published *tankobon* was on March 2013, 2013, stuck at volume 7 (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry_Marshmallow)).

Does anyone know what happened to him and his works?

Comment: There are some claims online saying barasui is suffering from 'physicall weakness'. All though I can't find any concrete sources.

Comment: i can confirm a source of what @Dimitrimx said and that's on [manga updates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/authors.html?id=707). it cites it's source as the Japanese Wikipedia however has i don't read Japanese well i can't confirm that so someone who can read japanese might want to see if they can find it on Wikipedia

Comment: @Memor-X I checked the wikipedia, but saw no such mention. Hence my "can't find sources" ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Ichigo Mashimaro* is still being published, albeit slowly and irregularly**. The author, Barasui, was on hiatus *due to a sudden illness on 2015-08-29*, but the rest of hiatuses were due to "the author's circumstance" until recently.

---

Regarding the serialization on *Monthly Dengeki Daioh*, according to the [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dengeki_Daioh#In_Dengeki_Daioh), the title is still on-going. It's hinted clearer on the [Japanese counterpart](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%88%E5%88%8A%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E9%9B%BB%E6%92%83%E5%A4%A7%E7%8E%8B#.E9.9B.91.E8.AA.8C.E3.82.AA.E3.83.AA.E3.82.B8.E3.83.8A.E3.83.AB) since it's included in the 現在連載中の作品 (currently serialized title) category instead of 休載中 (on hiatus).

Regarding the author, Barasui, according to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%B0%E3%82%89%E3%82%B9%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC#.E4.BD.9C.E5.93.81.E3.81.AE.E7.89.B9.E5.BE.B4), there's a remark about his irregular publishing time (or, *hiatus*) because of his unusually slow writing pace:

- He was on hiatus from edition *2009-5* to *2010-2* (10 months)
- Even if he did publish it, it was only an average of 5-6 pages including the cover page. However, the illustration was so detailed and each chapter could stand alone, making it a short-story manga
- In edition *2015-12*, he only published 8 pages compared to his previous usual 18 pages (also, compared to *Yotsuba to!*'s 28 pages)

Regarding the title itself, according to [Japanese Wikipeda](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8B%BA%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8D#.E5.8D.98.E8.A1.8C.E6.9C.AC) about the published date of the *tankobon*:

> - Volume 5: 2007-04-27
> - Volume 6: 2009-02-27 (1 year and 10 months later)
> - Volume 7: 2013-03-27 (**4 years and 1 month later**)
>
> <sup>(parentheses mine)</sup>

**However**, according to the specialized wiki on [atwiki (Japanese)](https://www37.atwiki.jp/mashimaro_wiki/pages/38.html),

- 2017-05-27: Chapter 78 (4 pages) was published in edition *2017-07*
- 2017-06-27: Chapter 78 (12 pages) was published in edition *2017-08*, no plan for next chapter's number and announcement
- 2017-07-27: Barasui is on hiatus **to work on the next *tankobon***
- 2017-08-10: **The 8th volume appeared on [Amazon Japan](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4048933949/), to be released on 2017-11-27**
- 2017-10-18: The author mentioned the release for the next *tankobon* on 2017-11-27 (on [Barasui's image storehouse (Japanese)](https://web.archive.org/web/20171020093845/http://bara.sakura.ne.jp/))

Comment: do you know what's the mean of this ? `電撃大王11月号発売。 
苺ましまろは告知通り休載です。 ` i used google translate and it said `Dengeki Daio November issue released.
Ichigo Mashimaro is closed as announced.` what does it mean by closed ?

Comment: @Gagantous It means "Ichigo Mashimaro is on-hiatus, as announced (before)". [休載](http://jisho.org/word/%E4%BC%91%E8%BC%89) can mean either "nonappearance in print" or "stopping publication". It means the former in this case.

Comment: When you see stuff like [this](https://imgur.com/FsceQO2), all the "mysterious illnesses" that mangaka suffer from suddenly become a lot less mysterious.